# How to create a graph with multiple grouped bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a chart using `ggplot2` with multiple grouped bars. In my dataset, I need to choose three columns so that this chart is grouped according to this sketch I made:

[image]

**CODE:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

DOPTransformationsMean %>% 
      select(SPL, AddedFields, ModifiedFields, RemovedFields) %>% 
      gather(Var,Val,-SPL) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(SPL, Val, group = Var)) + 
      ylab("Quantity") +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.3) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("solid", "solid", "solid")) + 
      scale_color_manual(labels = c("Added Fields", "Modified Fields", "Removed Fields"), values=c('#b30000','#00b300','#00b3b3')) + 
      theme_bw(base_size = 30) + 
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.title=element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=27), legend.direction="vertical") +
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(seq(0, (max(x) + 1) * 1.1)))))
```

**CODE RESULT:**

[image]

**DATASET:**

```
SPL,AddedClasses,ModifiedClasses,RemovedClasses,AddedMethods,ModifiedMethods,RemovedMethods,AddedImports,RemovedImports,AddedFields,ModifiedFields,RemovedFields
Reminder-PL,49,76,0,99,78,1,43,0,62,0,2
Iris-PL,84,21,4,14,8,0,34,0,2,0,0
```

I followed a similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57503173/error-geom-point-requires-the-following-missing-aesthetics-y-when-using-geom) where it is possible to generate a line chart, but by grouping my dataset, I couldn't get the bars to be grouped.

Comment: Examples here: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.html   Just need to add `geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.3, position = "dodge") +`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell `ggplot` to fill the bars according to the groups in the `aes` part of the plot.

```
DOPTransformationsMean %>% 
    select(SPL, AddedFields, ModifiedFields, RemovedFields) %>% 
    gather(Var,Val,-SPL) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(SPL, Val, group = Var, fill = Var)) + 
    ylab("Quantity") +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.3, position = "dodge") +
    scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Added Fields", "Modified Fields", "Removed Fields"),
                      values=c('#b30000','#00b300','#00b3b3')) + 
    theme_bw(base_size = 30) + 
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.title=element_blank(),
          legend.position = "bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=27), 
          legend.direction="vertical") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = function(x) unique(floor(pretty(seq(0, (max(x) + 1) * 1.1)))))
```

[image: example]