# How to solve: geom_linerange requires the following missing aesthetics: x, ymin, ymax

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am facing this error. I tried the solutions discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57503173/error-geom-point-requires-the-following-missing-aesthetics-y-when-using-geom) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459866/ggplot2-error-geom-point-requires-the-following-missing-aesthetics-y), to no avail. Clearly, there is something I am missing, not certain what. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
dt3<-structure(list(employee_name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), min_salary = c(10L, 
11L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 10L), mean_salary = c(15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 15L), max_salary = c(20L, 21L, 17L, 17L, 21L, 20L), category_boss = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Junior", "Senior"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

ggplot(dt3) + geom_point(aes(x=mean_salary,y=employee_name,colour=category_boss),position = position_dodge(-.5)) + 
    geom_linerange(aes(xmin=min_salary,xmax=max_salary,y=employee_name,colour=category_boss),
                   position = position_dodge(-.5))

Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: y, xmin, xmax
Error: geom_linerange requires the following missing aesthetics: x, ymin, ymax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `geom_linerange` only allows a range for `y` as indicated by the error. So Just flip your `x` and `y` values, and then use `coord_flip` to swap the `x` and `y` axes when plotting.

```
ggplot(dt3) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=mean_salary, x=employee_name, colour=category_boss), 
    position = position_dodge(-.5)) + 
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min_salary, ymax=max_salary, x=employee_name, colour=category_boss),
    position = position_dodge(-.5)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Just use `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,30), breaks=seq(0,30,15),labels = c("0\n(unfair)", "15\n(reasonable)", "15\n(fair)"))` The `ylim()` makes hard cuts and doesn't leave room for the labels.

Comment: You probably just have the wrong data types. You should open a new question with another reproducible example that matches your new data.